# Converting JS camelcase DOM style properties into valid CSS properties?

Tags: javascript, css, dom

I want to take any camelcase property on `CSSStyleDeclaration` and get the corresponding kebabcase CSS property. E.g. converting `marginLeft` to `margin-left`. Is there a built-in function that does this? I don't want to simply convert camelcase into kebabcase because there's no guarantee that it'll always work.

Comment: `no guarantee that it'll always work` - why not? did you know you can `element.style['margin-left'] = ... etc`

Comment: E.g. `cssFloat` is one property where the kebabcase version doesn't work. AFAIK nowhere in the specs guarantee than camel -> kebab would always work

Comment: how old is the oldest browser you want to support? `cssFloat` (and `styleFloat`) is for old browsers (talking pre IE9)

Comment: Definitely not IE9, but it's possible that browsers might add another property where the conversion doesn't work, so if a built-in solution exists, that'll be better

Comment: just use `element.style['margin-left']` etc

Comment: That has nothing to do with my use-case: converting React styles to transition value

Comment: what exactly are these "react styles" you speak of?

Comment: `style={{ marginLeft: 123 }}`

Answer (score 4):

Function using regex:

```
function CamelToSnake(string) {
    return string.replace(/([a-z]|(?=[A-Z]))([A-Z])/g, '$1-$2').toLowerCase();
};

CamelToSnake("marginLeft")
```